# creating pos tagger for new language using RNN in tensorflow using python

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

when I run the program, it shows the errors:
ValueError: in user code:

```
File "C:\Users\ICT4D\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2169, in predict_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\ICT4D\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2155, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\ICT4D\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2143, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.predict_step(data)
File "C:\Users\ICT4D\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2111, in predict_step
    return self(x, training=False)
File "C:\Users\ICT4D\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\ICT4D\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5126, in rnn
    final_outputs = tf.compat.v1.while_loop(

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'hidden_layer' (type GRU).

Input tensor `init_h:0` enters the loop with shape (1, 500), but has shape (None, 500) after one iteration. To allow the shape to vary across iterations, use the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop to specify a less-specific shape.

Call arguments received by layer 'hidden_layer' (type GRU):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1, 400), dtype=float32)
  • mask=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=bool)
  • training=False
  • initial_state=None
```

I am trying to create new POS tagger model using RNN for my new own language. I have labeled/annotated csv file. the csv file has two columns (word, pos).

When I enter the test data (it my be separated f). I expected the output are: new pos tagger model, tagged/labeled text, model accuracy, performance, precision.
The code is below: